# Integral inequality for $|f(x)|^2$ and $|\nabla f|$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am desperately trying to solve the following problem:

Let $ f \in C^1_c(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (continuously differentiable with compact support), show that
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |f(x_1,x_2)|^2 \ d\lambda_2(x_1,x_2) \leq (\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} |\nabla f(x_1,x_2)| \ d\lambda_2(x_1,x_2))^2$.

So far I was able to show that:
$ f(x_1,x_2) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} f(t,x_2) \ d\lambda_1(t)$.
Furthermore, I was trying to use the well known inequality $ \sqrt{\left|ab\right|} \leq \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} $ in order to change $|\nabla f(x_1,x_2)|$ into a product of two partial derivatives and try to substitute them with $ f(x_1,x_2) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_1} f(t,x_2) \ d\lambda_1(t)$. I also tried applying Fubini and Hölder, without any luck. I do not see how I can make further progress.

I would very much appreciate further hints.

Comment: What is $λ_1$ and $λ_2$?

Comment: It is the notation for one or two dimensional lebesgue integration

Comment: Can you think of an example. Because I think this is actually not true since $f \in C^1_c$ where $c$ is a compact set and $f$ has to be continuous, thus we cannot have $f \neq 0$ and $ \nabla f = 0$

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment: My example was e. g. a large square where $f = 1$, and then it falls of to $0$ outside. Then the LHS would grow quadratically with the side of the square, but since there is a square in the formula for the RHS, this could actually work.

Comment: It is however false that $f(x_1,x_2) = ∫_{-∞}^{x_1}f(t,x_2)\,\mathrm d t$ in general. Why?

Comment: I agree. I miss writing the partial derivative in my question. I have edited it

Comment: Are you familiar with proofs of the Poincare inequality? This looks very similar

Comment: @whpowell96 sadly I am not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done! If you use that $f(x,y) = ∫_{-∞}^x ∂_tf(t,y) \,\mathrm d t$, and similarly for $\overline{f(x,y)}$, then you get four integrals in the LHS. You also have four integrals in the RHS. All that remains is to make proper use of absolute values (and vector norms) and inequalities.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to obtain four integrals on the right hand side? And what do you exactly mean with $\bar{f}(x, y)$? I understand that I can obtain four integrals on the left hand side by splitting the integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$ up into to iterated integrals over $\mathbb{R}$ and then replacing |f(x,y)| once with the integral of the partial derivative with respect to $x$ and once with the integral with respect to $y$. However, I do not see how to obtain four integrals on the right hand side

Comment: $|f|^2 = f\bar f$, so $\iint|f(x,y)|^2\,\mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy = \iint∫_{-∞}^x∂_{x'}f(x',y)\,\mathrm dx' ∫_{-∞}^y∂_{y'}\bar f(x,y')\,\mathrm dy'\,\mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy$.

Comment: What do you mean with $\bar{f}$? I think I get that for the left hand side, if i pull the absolute values inside the integrals from negative infinity to x or y. However, I do not see the connection to the right hand side. There I only have the double integral. How should I obtain an extra two integrals there?

Comment: $\bar f$ is the complex conjugate of $f$. I thought $f$ was complex valued since you wrote $|f|^2$. If not, then $|f|^2 = f^2 =ff$, and just drop the bars! On the right hand side you have an integral squared. What do you have on the left hand side?

Comment: On the left hand side I have:
$\int (\int( \int_{-\infty}^{x} \partial_x' f(x',y) \ dx')*( \int_{-\infty}^{x} \partial_y' f(x,y*) \ dy') \ dx \ dy $
On the right hand side I have:
$(\int \int \sqrt{\partial_x \partial_y} \ dx \ dy) *(\int \int \sqrt{\partial_x \partial_y} \ dx \ dy) $

So I see that there are four integrals now, but is there a formula that gives the desired inequality?

Comment: The function $f$ maps into the reals. I don't know why I put additional absolute values around $f$.

Comment: Look at the left hand side. It is not greater than the same expression with absolute values around the two integrands, so you can make this comparison. Then you have nonnegative integrands. Can you utilise this property to compare it to something that can be broken up into a product of integrals?

Comment: The only thing I can think off right now that allows me to split up an integral would be hölder's inequality. Then the integrals with absolute values around the integrands would be in the $L^1$ norm, however they still depend on x so I do not think that I can write the integrals of the partial derivatives as an $L^1$ norm.

Comment: It is much simpler than that. The integrand is nonnegative, so if you increase the integration domain you will not get something smaller.

Comment: I understand, that I can integrate the product of the two integrals inside the double integral on the left hand side over $ \mathbb{R}$.  I currently have manipulated the left hand side as follows:
$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\partial_x f| ) * \int_{\mathbb{R}} |\partial_y f| ) $.
And the right hand side is:
$ [\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (\sqrt{\partial_x f \cdot \partial_y f})] *[\int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} (\sqrt{\partial_x f \cdot \partial_y f})]$
But I do not see why they should be equal or why the left hand side should be still smaller

Comment: It is important to keep track of the variables! You have now that the original LHS $≤ \iiiint |∂_{x'}f(x',y)| |∂_{y'}f(x,y')|\,\mathrm dx'\,\mathrm dy'\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = \iint |∂_{x'}f(x',y)| \,\mathrm dx' \,\mathrm dy \iint |∂_{y'}f(x,y')|\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy'$. Now you can rename $x'$ to $x$ and $y'$ to $y$ if you so wish. Does this look similar to the original RHS?

Comment: I see what you did, and why it was helpful to remove the bound for the integrals of the partial derivatives. However, the original RHS had a the product of different partial derivatives under the square root. This is the only difference between them. Sadly I do not see why I would be allowed to change $ | \partial_x' f(x',y)| $ to $ | \sqrt([\partial_x' f(x',y) \partial_y' f(x,y') |) $

Comment: It is not the square root of the product, the length of the vector $v = (x,y)$ is $|v| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. We always have $|x| ≤ |v|$ and $|y| ≤ |v|$ (Why?).

Comment: Oh, thank you! Now the two sides are actually equal apart from renaming variables. Thank you very much for your patience in explaining it to me.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped! You can mark the answer as accepted if you wish.